# How to maintain the width of the cipher image in ECC Image Encryption from Singh and Singh (2015)?

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation

I am a beginner in cryptosystems and I hope I would be accepted in the community.

I was trying to implement [Singh and Singh (2015)](http://283185018_Image_Encryption_using_Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography) ECC image encryption algorithm on Matlab.

I have been able to encrypt and decrypt images successfully with the algorithm. However, the width of my cipher image increases by (1/group) x plain image width.

group = log p / log 256

where p = prime number of the finite field

We initially take "group" number of pixels, convert them to a number of base 256 or 258[if we add 1 or 2 to the pixels randomly to reduce correlation] and point-add encryption to this 'big Integer'. But when we bring this big Integer (of base 256 or 258) to pixels, we have group+1 pixels. This is increasing the width of the image. However, according to the results, this should not be the case.

Actually, I cannot comprehend step 8 of the 4.1 Image Encryption process from this paper.

Can you please help me understand this?